# Mithrandir's chat puzzle!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, visual, steganography, imgur-maze

So Mithrandir's [chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/133031/mithrandir) has a puzzle:

> Hello. There's a puzzle here. You will need EG7Rx. However, you start at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSUe2.png

That URL is this picture:

[image]

Can you help to solve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Every imgur gives a letter for the future one.
>  Here's the list -
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSUe2.png x
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/voWId.png w
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCdul.png P
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnklt.png Y
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/v60QU.png x

**Which finally gives**

> [image]

**Text version -**

> Znel jnf yvggyr.
>  Fur unq na byqre oebgure anzrf Senax.
>  Gurve zbgure Anapl jnf n fubeg jbzna.
>  Fb jnf gurve Cncn.
>  Senax jnf gur bqq bar bhg, orvat gnyy.

**Decoding the above**

> Using **n** as the key or applying rot-13 we get -
>  *Mary was little.*
>  *She had an older brother names Frank.*
>  *Their mother Nancy was a short woman.*
>  *So was their Papa.*
>  *Frank was the odd one out, being tall.*

**Now**

> [image]

**Text version**

> 'pomsre. l'a vwtphgfoh. rkog geq
>  gwspmaxzg, bmekh? ukvb dg n biexznb
>  tscnyo sl wvr wegq gvdi. phoqi jmu mbev
>  lhlg mlyozrxkc? dv, oex rkseo mq qcao...
>  rmz wf dlc hbq. nslh wf issu ehowr.
>  l vnfi nxh lyyp iwakp yqgjov fhfr.
>  biyozl, sx'q hofi xm iwan. m'k zovdmlj.
>  grbmmxgyi, cmx'fr cxgoz yysilbt?
>  kqycwaq. amz, mbe'vc vhhlfmub.
>  rbq... kdmoo hm vczoxflbt opqh?
>  grbmmxgyi, pcdjr! yqe, jc ngew dzeoebb...
>  anx. ithflyrc, jwio xflg tec phd.
>
>  lyy'th tvxmqksq. lyr zvnd'w rks nxwuhf?

As @Gareth already figured out the key, trying to look at the note we get

> little Mary -> m
>  Older Brother Frank -> F
>  Nancy was short -> n
>  Short Papa -> p
>  Frank Tall -> F
>
>
>  This gives another imgur https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFnpF.png
>  [image]
>  Searching the same in the Chat gives the result as
>  *[Bilge, thou franchok! Thy key is DONKEY!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=34945211#34945211)*
>
>  And hence, the key is DONKEY!
>  Yay! Happy to discover the camouflaged Donkey. :)

Finally

> Applying **DONKEY** as the key we get
>  '**m**azing. **i**'m impressed. **t**hat was difficult, right? **h**ard as a regular puzzle on the main site. **r**eady for your next challenge? **a**h, but there is none... **n**ow is the end. **d**one is your quest. **i** have put your final answer here. **r**eally, it's easy to find. **i**'m waiting. **s**eriously, you're still looking? **a**mazing. **w**ow, you're stubborn. **e**rm... maybe do something else? **s**eriously, leave! **o**mg, go away already... **m**an. **e**veryone, give this guy rep. you've finished. but what's the answer?

Which is

> First letter of each sentence **MITHRANDIR IS AWESOME**

Comment: Now you must figure out what the lines about Mary and family are... Mwahaha.

Comment: Transcript: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35345399#35345399

Comment: Feeding the "'pomsre" text to an automated Vigenere solver and playing a bit yields the key DONKEY which gives English text on decoding. Presumably there's something concealed in it by some means.

Comment: First letters of sentences in the decoded text say MITHRANDIRISAWESOMEYB.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan that happens to be the answer, without the last two. You still have to find how to get the key, though.

Comment: Isn't "Using n as the key" simply rot 13?

Comment: @Ankoganit Yeah. :) Let me update that.

Comment: You're wrong about mary, Frank, nancy, papa, and Frank... ;)

Comment: @Will I still don't get it. I can connect Frank to [Francis the Mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_the_Talking_Mule)